# Need for gksudo for "Install new software" in eclipse

Tags: 10.10, eclipse

I have been developing for android on eclipse for a while now, and my experience with the eclipse environment on Ubuntu10.10 has not been a smooth one.

With the repo install of eclipse I have had to sudo eclipse to install the required components for android development. (a big red flag for me)

I tried today to install updates for the eclipse and android platform and my eclipse installation seems to have broken horribly.

I can no longer find and of the urls for new software if i gksudo it, if I run it in user mode it fails (as it always has) with permissions problems. I have chowned user:user all my eclipse and android related private/user files.

This is a system running ubuntu 10.10 with gnome2.x.   On my kubuntu 11.10 install it work a lot better.

- Is there an easy fix to this?
- Is the repo version of eclipse broken?
- Should I do a clean install for just my user? (if so can I retain my previously installed software? the installation process is very time consuming) I saw there was a previous post here recommending this for new installations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is no longer the case if you install from repository.  Tested on 12.04 LTS Beta.

See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119754/software-location-after-installing-via-ubuntu-software-center/119771#119771) question with screenshots for verification.