# Software location after installing via Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: software-center, eclipse

Let me tell you my problem: I just move from Windows 7 to Ubuntu and I'm trying to setup my programming environment. I installed Eclipse via Ubuntu Software Center, then opened it and installed additional plugins.
 Problem came up when I tried to install Subclipse: according to the official guide, I installed JavaHL, but that damned library wasn't automatically linked by Eclipse, so I was told to "*Note that JavaHL does not install in a location that is on Eclipse's default path, so eclipse must be launched with **-vmargs -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jni***".
Yes I know I have to modify eclipse.ini and add that vmargs line, but where is eclipse.ini??? I opened /usr/bin, the eclipse.exe is there but I can't found the rest.
I really don't want to remove this Eclipse and download another from Eclipse download page, because I will have to reinstall every plugins again. Please can anyone tell me how to find the directory which contains software which installed via USC? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You won't find your files in /usr -- that belongs to the root (the system). Programs may be stored there, but not the settings.

Unlike Windows, Linux stores user files in each user's own home folder, so that no two users can interfere with each other.

Look in your own home folder. The .ini file will probably be in a hidden folder, e.g. .eclipse (note the leading dot).

Open Nautilus (your file manager) > View > Show Hidden Files (or press Ctrl-H) to see your hidden folders and files.

Comment: Goto usr/share/applications 
you can see installed apps there

Comment: @PaddyLandau: You are right. I found the ".eclipse" folder in my Home. But I couldn't find the "eclipse.ini" there, only a "eclipse.ini.ignored"??? Guess I'm going to install new fresh Eclipse, not via USC anymore? It gave me so much problem >_<

Comment: @AnhTuan Next time, if you get familiar to the [terminal](http://askubuntu.com/q/38162/6969), try to run `locate eclipse.ini`

Comment: @AnhTuan - Check the solution below.  It's verified working with the install from software center.

Comment: You may want to have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/8419099 This seems to answer your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How I installed subclipse
Changed `/home/username/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.7.0_155965261/configuration/eclipse.ini.ignored`
to `/home/username/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.7.0_155965261/configuration/eclipse.ini` just in case.

Installed subversion and the java wrapper
`sudo apt-get install subversion libsvn-java`
Check the version `svn --version` On 12.04 it's 1.6
I went to "Help->Install new software"
[image]
Added the matching site for svn integration.  Make it match the version of libsvn.
[image]
Installed the full load of packages
[image]
Restarted eclipse from the command line to check for errors
I don't get any

I pulled an SVN repo to verify it working...ffmpeg svn is still up btw

Comment: Thank you very much! This line solves my problem "http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x". I've tried to install Subclipse 1.8 and of course it wasn't compatible with my svn, but it threw a error dialog about JavaHL and that confused me. But when I followed your guide and installed Subclipse 1.6, everything was ok ^_^